# Transformar string em algoritmo

Tags: python, algoritmo

Alguém sabe me dizer se existe uma forma de eu transformar uma string em algoritmo ? por exemplo: a = "1 + 1" => b = 1 + 1. Para exemplos simples é tranquilo criar um interpretador de string, o problema é que eu vou chegar em coisas mais complexas como "(x**2 - 1)/(x - 1)".

nota: eu considerei a biblioteca SymPy.

Comment: Você quer um avaliador de expressões numéricas?
 Em C# você pode usar `CodeDom` https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/codedom-calculator-evaluating-C-Sharp-math-expressions-dynamica/

Comment: Exato. Porem procuro para python. Mas obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Use o eval() para avaliar o código e retornar a melhor interpretação para ele.

a = "15 + 2"
print(eval(a))

O eval() é tão útil, que da até pra transformar strings em variáveis com ele, e tambem existe o 'exec' que executa uma string como se fosse um código veja ambos trabalhando no mesmo exemplo:

a = 5
b = 8
c = 7

for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']: # Transforma strings em variaveis.

```
exec'print(eval(x))'
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode converter sua string em uma expressão sympy usando a função `parse_expr ()` no módulo `sympy.parsing.sympy_parser`.

```
>>> from sympy.abc import a, b, c
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
>>> sympy_exp = parse_expr('(a+b)*40-(c-a)/0.5')
>>> sympy_exp.evalf(subs={a:6, b:5, c:2})
448.000000000000
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13225555/194717

Comment: Ok, Encontrei um jeito simples também. O eval. exemplo: x = 0;
print(eval('x * 1 + 2'));

Comment: Só tomaria um pouco de cuidado com o eval. A discussão na resposta aceita desta pergunta é interessante, vale dar uma olhada. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice